# Amortised Complexity for Iterators

Tags: java, iterator, complexity-theory

I am required to implement an iterator function in Java for a balanced tree for example AVL tree with an amortised complexity of O(1+log(N/M)) and am not sure what this means? Any links or explanation will be very helpful..Thanks

Comment: What is N?  What is M?  You need to describe what these constants are for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Apologies, N is the number of nodes in my tree i.e values and M is the number of nodes i have visited in ascending order....

Comment: (O(1 + log n) is equivalent to O(log n).)

Answer (score 1):

It means that for every consecutive call to the iterator's `next()` method, the complexity of that method call will decrease. for a tree with N nodes, the first call should have a complexity of O(log(N)), the following invocation should have O(log(N/2)), etc.
to really understand complexity you should have some background in mathematics and computer science. for a short and ambiguous explanation read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). for a deeper understanding of this topic you should start with Corman's [Introduction to algorithms](http://books.google.co.il/books/about/Introduction_To_Algorithms.html?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&redir_esc=y)